# What is the equivalent of VB's Replace(str1, str2, str3) in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, file

In both VB and C#, I know that when we replace a string, we use: `FILE.Replace` and we don't assign the statement to a variable. For example, `File.Replace(text1, text2, text1);`

However, I have a VB code that I want to use and convert it into C# code and I am very confused about how the `Replace` was used.

The VB code is working properly!

Here is the VB code:

```
    Dim pdfTemplate As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "PDFs\2017-I9.pdf")
    pdfTemplate = Replace(pdfTemplate, "bin\Debug\", "")


    Dim fields = New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {
      {"textFieldLastNameGlobal", Me.tbLast.Text},
      {"textFieldFirstNameGlobal", Me.tbFirst.Text},
      {"textFieldMiddleInitialGlobal", Mid(Me.tbMiddle.Text, 1, 1)},
      {"textFieldOtherNames", Me.tbOtherName.Text}
    }
```

The line **pdfTemplate = Replace(pdfTemplate, "bin\Debug\", "")** is what confused me and I couldn't convert it to C#.

By the way, the VB code was written and posted here, but I forgot who is the person. I want to give the author the credit even though I am not mentioning him/her.

Below is my attempt to make similar code in C#

```
pdfTemplate = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/PDFs/2017-I9.pdf");
pdfTemplate = File.Replace(pdfTemplate, "bin\\Debug\\", "");

        var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"textFieldLastNameGlobal", EL.LastName},
            {"textFieldMiddleInitialGlobal", EL.MiddleName},
            {"textFieldFirstNameGlobal", EL.FirstName},
            {"textFieldOtherNames", EL.OtherLastName}
        };
```

I get error on **pdfTemplate = File.Replace(pdfTemplate, "bin\Debug\", "");**

Comment: _pdfTemplate = pdfTemplate.Replace(@"bin\Debug\", "");_ notice the @ before the string to escape the \ character

Comment: @Steve, that worked very well. Thank you!

Comment: *is what confused me* And why your code didn't work? You can write `"\\bin\\Debug\\"` or `@"\bin\Debug\"`. I see the first variant in your code. So, what didn't work? Is there some error?

Comment: @JohnyL he is using **File**.Replace that has nothing to do with replacing a part of a string with another part

Comment: @Steve Oops! My bad! Missed `File.` part :)

Comment: You get error? **which** error?

Comment: Yes, actually my issue wasn't with `\` or `@`. My issue was with using the Replace. You wrote it the right way which I was missing

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I got a syntax error but it was fixed. Thank you all

Comment: @AhmedAli Then why you were using `File` in the first place?

Comment: And know that `Replace` in VB is string replacement, whereas `File.Replace` is **file** replacement, you want `String.Replace` in C#. Your statements in your question about what you *know* is what caused this problem, you *know* that in both C# and VB.NET you use `File.Replace` to replace text, which is simply not true.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, you are correct. I was wrong about it

Answer (score 2):

The C# code that is equivalent to VB `Replace(str1, str2, str3)` is `str1.Replace(str2, str3)`.

So this line:

```
pdfTemplate = Replace(pdfTemplate, "bin\Debug\", "")
```

should become this:

```
pdfTemplate = pdfTemplate.Replace("bin\Debug\", "")
```

Although that is not right either because in C#, the `\` character in a string escapes the next character, in which case the C# compiler is going to complain about an unrecognized escape sequence, as well as a newline in a constant string because first it doesn't understand what you mean by `\D`, then the `\"` escapes the quote which means it won't end the string.

You can either double up the backslashes, or put a `@` in front of the string, so either of the following should work:

```
pdfTemplate = pdfTemplate.Replace(@"bin\Debug\", "");
pdfTemplate = pdfTemplate.Replace("bin\\Debug\\", "");
```

Notice that I also added semicolons to the end of the statements.

---

**Word of warning**: For *path* manipulation it's usually better to use the [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) class in .NET as this is designed to correctly handle path-wise oddities.

For instance, if you happen to have a filenamed `Trashbin\Debug\File` you're going to end up with `TrashFile`, which is not quite right.

You could do this:

```
string templateFolder = Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath);
if (templateFolder.EndsWith(@"\\bin\\debug", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    templateFolder = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(templateFolder, "..", ".."));
string templateFile = Path.Combine(templateFolder, "PDFs", "2017-I9.pdf");
```

If you need the code to run on other operating systems than Windows you should use the `Path` class to find `Debug` and `bin` as well as other operating systems might use forward slashes or colons as path separators.

---

Note that [`File.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d9h163f(v=vs.110).aspx) does something completely different, it replaces a *file*, not contents of a string.

Comment: One last note of warning, know that `string.Replace(...)` is *case sensitive*, which means that if your string contains `Bin\Debug` or `bin\debug`, both of which are *textually* the same, but not *case-wise* identical, the string replacement will fail.